# When $\overline{H} \cap \overline{K} = \overline{H \cap K}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $N \trianglelefteq G$ and $H, K \leq G$.
When we have $\overline{H} \cap \overline{K} = \overline{H \cap K}$
(where $\overline{X}$ means the image of $X$ with natural map in $G / N$)?

I guess we should have $N \leq H \cap K$. Is there any weaker condition?

Comment: This is not true, you should assume $N \leq H$ or $N \leq K$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}$Prove instead that this is *not* true. Take for instance
$$
G = S_{3},\quad
N = \Span{(123)},\quad
H = \Span{(12)},\quad
K = \Span{(13)}.
$$

Of course there could be something special about group homomorphisms, but in general direct images of maps preserve unions, but not intersections. Whereas inverse images preserve both.

---

This was the answer to the previous question, which required to *prove* that the identity holds in general.

For the current question, all I am able to say is the following.

The identity is equivalent to $(H \cap K) N = H N \cap K N$. Clearly the left-hand side is contained in the right-hand side. By Dedekind's identity, we have
$$
H N \cap K N = (H N \cap K) N = (H \cap K N) N.
$$
So for the identity to hold we need $H N \cap K \le (H \cap K) N$ (or equivalently $H \cap K N \le  (H \cap K) N$). As noted in a comment, certainly $N \le H$ or $N \le K$ guarantee this.